# Remove Top Keyboard Panel

Tags: android

I use AdjustResize, and in some cases the highlighted panel may disappear, which leads to resizing the layout once again, which in my case does not look very good. Is there a way to hide this panel in advance?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add inputType **textNoSuggestions** to your editText

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```